# Parallel compilation of several numba functions

Tags: python, parallel-processing, compilation, multicore, numba

I am trying to use `numba` to compile several functions within my codebase to speed up execution. I have several thousand standalone functions that I am trying to compile with the `jit` decorator. While compiling my functions I notice that all the code is compiled within a single python process and only makes use of a single core within my machine. This results in compilation times often exceeding an hour. I am wondering if I can enable parallelization during the compilation step similar to `make -j <number of processors>`.

My functions are completely independent of each other and subsequent calls that utilize them are in a separate sub-module. Here is an example of the sort of functions that I would like to be able to compile in parallel:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, float64
@jit(float64[:](float64[:]),nopython=True,cache=True,fastmath=True,parallel=True,nogil=True)
def fun_0(x):
  return np.power(x,0)

@jit(float64[:](float64[:]),nopython=True,cache=True,fastmath=True,parallel=True,nogil=True)
def fun_1(x):
  return np.power(x,1)

@jit(float64[:](float64[:]),nopython=True,cache=True,fastmath=True,parallel=True,nogil=True)
def fun_2(x):
  return np.power(x,2)

@jit(float64[:](float64[:]),nopython=True,cache=True,fastmath=True,parallel=True,nogil=True)
def fun_3(x):
  return np.power(x,3)
```

The code is only illustrative of my use case. Alternate ways to structure my functions/modules may also be an acceptable solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Is the goal to increase the runtime performance, observed to get lowered by the `@decorator`-*"inlined"* JIT compilation of several thousand standalone functions?

### Solution :
 may use "AoT Compilation: i.e. Compiling code ahead of time"

> <sub>While Numba’s main use case is Just-in-Time compilation, it also provides a facility for Ahead-of-Time compilation (AOT).
>
>
>   **Limitations :**
>   
>
>   1) AOT compilation only allows for regular functions, not `ufuncs`.
>
>   2) You have to specify function signatures explicitly.
>
>   3) Each exported function can have only one signature (but you can export several different signatures under different names).
>
>   4) AOT compilation produces generic code for your CPU’s architectural family (for example “x86-64”), while JIT compilation produces code optimized for your particular CPU model.</sub>

### Warning :
 your code<sub>*as-is*</sub> seems to be prone to fall into [Amdahl's Law Trap](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3)

you will easily happen to pay way more on add-on overheads, than will ever receive back (from a (just) potential processing speedup - as more intensive memory-I/O-s and CPU-core cache re-use mechanics related constraints (both the absolute I/O ceilings and the relative losses of re-use efficiencies) do and will still work against your wish to get performance boosted )

> At least, you have been warned :o)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Would you know if the ahead of time compilation can occur in parallel?

Comment: You can change the target to eg. haswell. Of corse it would not run anymore on CPUs which don't have AVX2, FMA3,... Parallel also isn't supported right now....